# special alignment for simplifications to a big expression

Tags: equations, lyx, align

I want to show simplifications to a large expression with each step aligned at the equals sign below the original expression.  For example:

```
 AVERAGED_EXPONENTIAL_OF_INTEGRAL_HERE

    = SERIES_EXPANSION_OF_AVERAGED_INTEGRANDS_HERE

    = NON_ZERO_TERMS_IN_SERIES_HERE

    = SIMPLIFIED_RESULT_HERE
```

I am actually working in LYX.  Please let me know if you foresee problems with implementing the solution in LYX.  Thank you all for your help and your time!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Short hint of an answer: Insert --> Math --> AMS align Environment

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment a bit, you can do this with an `align` environment from `amsmath`, that in LyX is inserted via Insert --> Math --> AMS align Environment:

[image]

After doing that, you get a math environment with two boxes, just as if you insert a math matrix:

[image]

In the first box, you enter the expression on the left side of the equals sign, in the second box you enter the *equals sign itself* and the right hand side of the equality.

To start a new line hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which gives you a new pair of boxes below the first line:

[image]

Leave the left box empty, and write a new equals sign followed by the next step in the expansion in the right box:

[image]

The generates the following output:

[image]

Comment: Is there an easy way to incorporate the "title-like" LHS in the first line? Perhaps an ERT is the way to go with `\newcommand{\aligntitle}[1]{\makebox[2em][l]{$#1$}}` and using `\aligntitle{...}`.

Comment: @Werner Didn't think about that ... If you can think of a good way to do it with LaTeX I might be able to 'translate' it to LyX.